# Trigger a refresh of a jQuery color picker plugin on input field change

Tags: jquery, triggers, color-picker

I am currently using jQuery .click() method to update 15 text fields with simple color hex values i.e. like this document.form1.top_menu_bgcolor.value = '#FFFFFF';

I am also using ExColor for jQuery http://modcoder.org/ to display a killer color picker
http://modcoder.org/js/modcoder-1.1.js

**The problem is that when you click to update the fields, the color picker swatches don't get refreshed.**

How can I simply reactivate or refresh the swatches when the fields are changed? What can I call in the .click function below to refresh the swatches to the new hex string, input value?

Here's the JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $('document').ready(function() {

        // running ExColor
        $('#my_input_1').modcoder_excolor();
    $('#my_input_2').modcoder_excolor();
    $('#my_input_3').modcoder_excolor();
    $('#my_input_4').modcoder_excolor();
    $('#my_input_5').modcoder_excolor();
    $('#my_input_6').modcoder_excolor();
    $('#my_input_7').modcoder_excolor();
    $('#my_input_8').modcoder_excolor();
    $('#my_input_9').modcoder_excolor();
    $('#my_input_10').modcoder_excolor();
    $('#my_input_11').modcoder_excolor();
    $('#my_input_12').modcoder_excolor();
    $('#my_input_13').modcoder_excolor();
    $('#my_input_14').modcoder_excolor();
    $('#my_input_15').modcoder_excolor();    

        $('#theme01').click(function() {
            document.form1.top_menu_bgcolor.value = '#FFFFFF';
        document.form1.top_menu_bgcolor.focus();
        document.form1.top_menu_fontcolor.value = '#FFFFFF';
        document.form1.top_menu_bghovercolor.value = '#FFFFFF';
        document.form1.top_menu_fonthovercolor.value = '#FFFFFF';
        document.form1.left_menu_bgcolor.value = '#FFFFFF';
        document.form1.left_menu_fontcolor.value = '#FFFFFF';
        document.form1.left_menu_bghovercolor.value = '#FFFFFF';
        document.form1.left_menu_fonthovercolor.value = '#FFFFFF';
        document.form1.left_div_border.value = '#FFFFFF';
        document.form1.site_background_color.value = '#FFFFFF';
        document.form1.header_color.value = '#FFFFFF';
        document.form1.content_header_color.value = '#FFFFFF';
        document.form1.browser_bg_color.value = '#FFFFFF';
        document.form1.footer_color.value = '#FFFFFF';
        document.form1.footer_font_color.value = '#FFFFFF';

        });

</script>
```

And the HTML

```
<a href="#" id="theme01">Theme 1</a>


<input type="text" ID="my_input_1" name="top_menu_bgcolor" maxlength="7" value="#000000" size="10" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using something similar to:

```
   <script type="application/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function(){

      $("#theme01").click(function(){
       $("#myinput1").val('#aaafFF');   
       $('#myinput1').click();
       setTimeout( function(){
            $('#c3').blur();
            $('#c3').click();
            $('#c3').blur();}, 
       50);
   return false;
      });

      });
 </script>
```

where #c3 is a different div somewhere.

This will in effect, show and hide the modcoder fast enough the user does not see it.

**Edit**: Full Answer

```
        $("#theme01").click(function(){
            $("#myinput1").val('#aaaFFF');
            $('#myinput1').click();
            setTimeout( function(){$('#modcoder_ok').click();}, 50);
        });

        $("#theme02").click(function(){
            $("#myinput1").val('#222ccc');
            $('#myinput1').click();
            setTimeout( function(){$('#modcoder_ok').click();}, 50);
        });
```

And then in html:
     Theme 1
     Theme 2

I use two buttons, the delayed #modcode_ok.click() does a programmatically click of the ok button to select and refresh the color. 
On my computer the setTimeout at 50ms is too fast and I cannot see the popup. Maybe you need to adjust on your needs.

Comment: Thanks this did help... The only thing is I see the color picker window blink really fast and if you go to change the theme again it doesn't close the color picker. Is there any other way to do it?

Comment: I am not sure of your use case, but the edit allows to update the value and change the color as you want.